# Javascript/Jquery get all child divs that do not have a certain id and change display to none

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following divs, At the moment when the first one is changed the the corresponding div id in the second divs has its display property changed from none to block as they all  start out as none.

First Div

```
<div class="carousel">
   <div class="item active" id="ZS125-48A">...</div>
   <div class="item" id="FFKG-34">...</div>
   <div class="item" id="DSSS-56">...</div>
   <div class="item" id="ZSFD-48A">...</div>
</div>
```

Second Div

```
<section class="contentBikeTabbedMenus">
   <div id="ZS125-48ATab" class="active" style=" display: block;">...</div>
   <div id="FFKG-34Tab" class="" style=" display: block;">...</div>
   <div id="DSSS-56Tab" class="" style=" display: block;">...</div>
   <div id="ZSFD-48ATab" class="" style=" display: block;">...</div>
</section>
```

So the varible tabId1 has the id of the first active div and it finds the second div with the same name but with the word 'Tab' appended to it. It then changes its display property and adds the active class.

```
if($(tabId1).css('display') != 'block') {
    $(tabId1).css("display", "block").addClass('active');
}
```

How could i work it so that after this if, all the divs under `<section class="contentBikeTabbedMenus">` which dont have the id in the varible `tabId1`, i can change the css of them from display block to none.

Comment: @Vogel612 They are, he uses the `Tab` suffix

Comment: The ids are, the ids of the second div have the word 'Tab' appended to them. because i have the current id of the div, would it be possible to find all divs not with this id a and change there display property, thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about hiding them all first and then showing only the selected div?

```
$(".contentBikeTabbedMenus div").removeClass("active").hide();    
if($(tabId1).css('display') != 'block') {
    $(tabId1).css("display", "block").addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Tip: `.is(':hidden')`

Answer (score 0):

```
if( ! $(tabId1).is(':visible') ) {
    $('.contentBikeTabbedMenus').hide()
    $(tabId1).show().addClass('active');
}
```